# C++ plugin dll system

Tags: c++, dll, plugins, interface, abstract

I would like to add a dll plugin system to my c++ application.

After reading all I could find on the topic, I will use a class interface that has only pure virtual functions, and basic datatypes. Each plugin DLL will derive classes from this interface and expose them with a registration mechanism. It will include a destruction mechanism to ensure that new and delete for this class are not called across the DLL boundary.

But where should I import and export the interface? Do I need to make a kind of dummy DLL with no code, only exporting the class declaration? Or could I not import/export the class anywhere and just use it as a header in both app and plugins, passing only pointers to the class between the app and plugins?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I sugest you the following approach:

- Declare your plugin interface inside a common header file (used by
  the app and plugin)
- Your interface must have only virtual pure methods = 0, no data
  members.
- The virtual methods must use only primitive type and structures 
  (like to C interface). This for ABI compatibility. So the plugin can
  be developed with different compilers
- The plugin interface must provide two methods: CreateObject() and
  FreeObject(). The ABI code of the DLL know how create its object and
  delete its object.

I hope that this can help you.

Comment: OK so I do not need to export the interface classes, just to share the header.